# setUser is not a function when try to log in or register

Tags: reactjs, authentication, material-ui, react-hooks

here is the code [in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-diffie-vdwyl?file=/src/Appbar.js) in react hooks

i am trying to make login register through material Ui. it will be like when i try to register myself in register card. then i will click on login from appbar. then i should login in login card and appbar will show **you are logged in as {user}**

but everytime i try to login or register it is showing me setUser is not a function. where did i make the mistake?

Comment: where have you defined the setUser function?

Comment: In App.js.. const[user,setUser]=useState(‘’)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have passed props as `<Appbar user={user} setuser={setUser} handleClick={handleClick} />`

But you are using props in your Appbar component -

```
export default function Appbar({ user, setUser, handleClick }) {}
```

Your prop is named as `setuser` not `setUser`. You should match your props names properly.

EDIT::
same error in your content component. Please check your props for all components. Suggestiong - Use PropTypes to catch such errors

```
<Content user={user} setuser={setUser} click={click} />
```

EDIT:: Your logout doesn't work because you are using `onSubmit` on a div.

Change that to `form` and it will work. Native div doesn't have onSubmit prop

Comment: thanx for your reply....logout in the appbar is working but when i click click on logout ,it doesn't come back to previous login Register stage. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I edited your codesandbox and it should work now: https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-cherry-u729i

Comment: thanx for your reply....logout is working but when i click click on logout ,it doesn't come back to previous login Register stage. how can i do that?